# With @pytest.mark.parametrize (py.test), how to detect when data set exhausted

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I use @pytest.mark.parametrize to pass test data to a test function, then I use splinter (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/splinter) to conduct my tests. Though I would like to know when the data set passed with parametrize will exhausted to close brower when all test have been completed. That way I don't have to initialize new browser instance each time and when data set is exhausted I can close the browser, so the test are finishing cleanly.

I found this workaround :

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("controller, function, table, data, end",
    [('controller', 'function', 'table1', 'data1', {'end': False}),
     ('controller', 'function', 'table2', 'data2', {'end': True})])
def test_controller_function_table_data(controller, function, table, data, end):
    # Test stuff
    # ...
    if end['end'] is True:
        browser.quit()  # Close browser
```

The workaround is working ok, but I am curious to know if there is a way to check for data set exhaustion out of the box with parametrize... I did some search but can't found anything, I maybe just don't have the right keyword. I feel, like it could be a nice feature if not already implemented...

Thanks

Comment: Could you not do that in `setUp`/`tearDown`?

Comment: Maybe, but it seems much more work a for such a trivial thing...

Comment: Actually, this is how you are supposed to do such things.

Comment: Finally as you mention setup/teardown was the way to go and doesn't make the test execution much longer, what supprise me... So I solve it by create browser instance in setup_funciton() and browser.quit() in teardown_function()... I am not so sure if I should leave this question for further reference or not... It's a kind of false positive, but it may help other py.test beginner like me improve their knowledge. What do you think?